# добавление товара в корзину и сохранение в localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Пытаюсь написать корзину и вот в чем у меня вопрос.

При нажатии на кнопку добавления в корзину срабатывает такой код

```
i++;
total2.innerHTML = '(' + i + ')';
button.innerHTML = "Товар уже в корзине";
localStorage.setItem(i, productName);
```

И вот стал вопрос, как мне подсчитать и вывести количества товара в корзине?
Т.е. при клике на кнопку в localStorage добавляется `localStorage.setItem(1, productName);` А при заходе на страницу как мне вывести количество товара?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество пар ключ/значение хранящихся в localStorage

```
localStorage.length
```

Оба параметра метода setItem(), [должны быть строками](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Comment: Не подскажете по умолчанию localStorage.length равно 1?

Comment: нет, по умолчанию localStorage.length равно 0, вы можете это проверить очистив localStorage, методом localStorage.clear()

Comment: в том то и дело, как только я ставлю localStorage.clear() то localStorage.length равно 0, как только комментирую код и вывожу в консоль localStorage.length оно становится равно 1

Comment: удивительно, у меня такого нет, после того как я очистил localStorage, я удалил код очистки, оставив только вывод alert(localStorage) с комментарием, alert мне выдал 0, попробуйте в другом браузере протестировать, может быть это баг в браузере

Comment: ну вот смотрите krilof.bget.ru/e-store/ можете добавить любой товар в корзину и перейти в корзину, и браузер в одном из значений передаст null

Comment: я так и не смог понять как добавить товар в корзину( используйте хранение выбранных товаров на стороне сервера, посылая ему через AJAX post запрос

Comment: У меня шапка слетала, сейчас поправил, посмотрите пож-та, нажать в товаре нужно кнопку "заказать"

Comment: не работает корзина( а что мешает хранить на стороне сервера?

Comment: простите, что-то я загоняю( лучше в session

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, оказывается, битрикс автоматически добавляет localStorage.setItem(null, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Все пробрасываешь в массив => массив парсишь в json => json закидываешь в localstorage.

```
var list = [];

list.push({id: 5, 'name': 'someName5'})
list.push({id: 6, 'name': 'someName6'})
...

localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(list));`
```

Если надо посчитать, берешь из

```
var itemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem(1) // сейчас там строка
console.log(JSON.parse(itemsFromStorage).length); // количество
```

Comment: ну а если надо записать, берешь опять из localStorage записываешь новый элемент в массив, и обратно закидываешь в localStorage

Comment: Что за локальное хранилище? Я недавно маялся подобной задачей и было уйма проблем с куки. Я имею ввиду в чем разница между куки и этим?

Comment: тут есть API для управления, получение/отправка/очистка. Ну а вообще есть sessionStorage - хранит данные пока не закроется браузер, а localStorage можно удалить только с помощью javascript

Comment: я вроде бы про куки спрашивал... Они тоже хранятся после закрытия, но на указанный срок. Чем они хуже/лучше и когда для использования?

Comment: можно удалить с помощью js и не имеет срока хранения + готовое API самого браузера. а куки не имеют API, надо делать свои методы чтения/записи/удаления.